# If $f'(0)$ exists then show that $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f'(0)$ exists and that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this. I'm not looking for a full solution, but rather i'm looking for a hint to start this off. All I know is that $$f'(0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$.

EDIT: It appears that I was using a nonoptimal definition of the derivative for this exercise. Thank you for the responses!

Comment: I think you mean for $x_0$ to be $0$?

Comment: I have stated the formal definition of the derivative as given by my book.

Comment: In fact, if $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$, then $f$ is differentiable everywhere. That is a challenging problem!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the difference quotient

$$\frac{f(x + \Delta) - f(x)}{\Delta} = \frac{f(x)f(\Delta) - f(x)}{\Delta}$$

See what to do now?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need that $f$ is *differentiable* at $0$ -- being *continuous* at $0$ is sufficient for the conclusion.

Assume $f$ is not the everywhere zero function (which is clearly differentiable everywhere).

From the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ you can prove that $f(0)=1$, then $f(x)\ne 0$ everywhere, then $f(x)>0$ everywhere, and finally $f(x)=(f(1))^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Then, since $f$ is continuous at $0$, it will be continuous anywhere, and therefore it will equal $(f(1))^x$ for all $x$. And $(f(1))^x$ is differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write the derivative as

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)$ is defined to be $\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+y) - f(x)}{y}$ and

$$\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+y) - f(x)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)f(y) - f(x)}{y} = f(x)\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{f(y) - 1}{y} = f(x)f'(0)$$

since $f(0)= 1$ if $f$ is not identically $0$

If $f$ is identically $0$, $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$ still holds.

Comment: Therefore, $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$?

Comment: @Pubbie I've edited for anther case, to be complete

Comment: By identically $0$, do you mean if $f$ is constant?

Comment: @Pubbie yes, constant and equal to $0$

Answer (score 1):

For this function not to be constant and equal to $0$, $f(0)=1$. Fix an $x\in \mathbb{R}$. For $f$ to be differentiable at $x$, this limit must exist:

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)(f(h)-1)}{h}=f(x)\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
$$

And this last limit exists, given that the function is differentiable at $0$.